# Sending email forms in HTML without seeing outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

We are exploring different functions for mailing forms. (None of us are HTML'ers rather VB.net'ers.)

The code I found and understood is as follows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h3>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This opens the Outlook program and the user has to click send/receive in Outlook.

Can I send email forms in HTML without displaying the Outlook program as in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

Here i have pasted a complete code for sending mail without opening any outlook or using gmail credentials etc. It uses PHP for sending mail. hope this helps you.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
}

if(trim($_POST['ContactNum']) == '' && is_numeric($_POST['ContactNum'])) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $Contacting = trim($_POST['ContactNum']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted 
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '' && preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",$_POST['email']))  {
    $hasError = true;
}  else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//----------------------Email Validation-----------------//
    function EmVal($e)
    {
        return preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",$e);
    }


//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'abc@abc.com';
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments \n\nContact Number:\n $Contacting";
        $headers = 'From: WebBestow <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;}


}
 ?>
```

You can udpate fields as per your requirments. And set action="youpage.php". this code should be in html document of yourpage.php

Comment: errr PHP To be honnest is doh! for me namley I naver use it so I also now try to avoid it I never seam to be able to get the html to communicate with the PHP? example code is found on http://www.htmlforums.com/talent-center/t-form-help-67762.html#post438111 Nice I have a folder with my html and another with the PHP named contact.php as the site sugests I run my html all boxes there click send and now my contact.php file is displayed in the browser as just text??? what am i not doing right? (BTW I allways get this with php)

Comment: Well you gotta use php to send mail in order to send mail in your way without opening any mail program.