# When I click the send button of my contact form nothing happens on blogger

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi guys i have this form that if the user fills in the contact form on my blogger page it will be sent to my e-mail but when they click the send button nothing happens.

```
<form action='mailto:aaaa@yahoo.com' method='POST' name='contact-form'>
  <div>
    Name: 
  </div>
  <input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name'  size='30' type='text' value=''/>
  <div>
    Email:
  </div>
  <input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email'    size='30' type='text' value=''/>
  <div>
    Contact Number:
  </div>
  <input class='contact-form-number' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-number' name='number' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
  <div>
    Item Details:
  </div>
  <textarea class='contact-form-email-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' rows='5'/>
  <p/>
  <input class='submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Send'/>
  <div style='text-align: center; max-width: 450px; width: 100%'>
    <p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'/>
    <p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success- message'/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i included my codes on my question but it does not shows up is there a bug here in stackoverflow?????\

Comment: I strongly doubt that there is a bug on SO. You can stil Edit the question and include the code, but don't paste big amount of code - there is no sense in doing it.

Comment: i have been posting here in SO for a long time but it was just today that it happened...I included 4 spaces for the codes and it did not showed up I also tried editing it again but no luck..I think its a bug @TomasPastircak

Comment: after typing a text give some(enter)space and some(spacebar) and paste code

Comment: @KarthikManoharan ah ok :) I forgot to use enter before using spaces :) Thanks

Comment: @Log1c what page name do you mean sir? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `type='button'` to `type='submit'` in your button

Comment: Hi sir it worked but it executes outlook as the medium of sending the mail..Is there a way that there is no need to use outlook rather sends the mail automatically to my yahoo mail account after clicking the send button. Thanks

Comment: you need to use some server side code to without using outlook.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634363/sending-email-forms-in-html-without-seeing-outlook

Comment: What kind of back end server code? for linux or windows?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have contact form gadget in your sidebar. You need to add & hide the contact form on the sidebar. After that a contact form added to a blog page will work. Learn how to create a [contact us page for Blogger](https://www.techprevue.com/contact-us-page-for-blogger/).

Regards